# Express param length limit for GET

Tags: node.js, express

I have a nodejs app where I am using express for REST APIs.

One of the api is which accepts a SQL query, runs it on a DB and returns the JSON response. Everything was working fine until I tested the api with a long sql query.
Upon debugging , I noticed that the SQL query is trimmed automatically.

Is there a limit on the length of the param that can be passed in the GET URL?

This is what my api looks like

```
app.get('/v1/runsql/:query', (req, res) => {
let result = runQuery.executeQuery(req.params.query);
..... execute some more code here
})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Node enforces a limit not on the URL itself, but on the overall request headers (including URI)   Requested headers + URI can not be more than 80 kb.

Also, it's an incredibly bad idea to expose an API that allows arbitrary SQL queries regardless of whether they're on the URL or not. Most applications spend a lot of effort trying to prevent arbitrary SQL from querying records that shouldn't be exposed, dropping tables, etc.  Intentionally exposing an endpoint like this just feels like you're asking for trouble.

Comment: thanks for the response. I agree that running arbitrary sql is a bad idea, but   what about scenarios where there is a check in place that allows 1) only select queries 2) Allow read operations from a  list of tables.

Comment: It’s your system, @A-D, do what you want. But if it’s me, and I can know in advance what statements and tables are allowed, I’d just make endpoints that map to those under the hood and still not allow the actual SQL string to be passed over the wire.

Comment: @A-D If you're just executing arbitrary SQL over the network anyway, why not just connect directly to the database?  You'll remove a layer of complexity.  If instead you want this API layer for some reason, consider abstracting the database so that you can change that underlying database system without breaking the application that uses the API.  There are reasons this is a common architecture... you just need to decide which scenarios apply to you.

Answer (score 0):

The http protocol not limit the length of url, but the browser and server(whatever Node or others) do the limit. If you really want to implement that, you may use a **POST** method instead of **Get**

And the http protocol spec set that: The server may return code **414** if the url length is out of limit