# Node js REST Client Scaling the Data collection

Tags: node.js, rest, scaling, horizontal-scaling, node-rest-client

I have a scenario where my node js client collects data from rest api.

**Scenario** : my api endpoint is like this  **http://url/{project}**
where **project** is parameter. the project comes from a Database table.

here is my procedure:

1. I am getting all the projects names from Database to a list
2. using a loop calling rest endpoint for every project in the list

**My Query**: If I have less number of projects in the Database this procedure working fine but, If I have around 1000 projects to collect, the requests are taking long time and some times failing due to timeout errors.

How can I scale this process so that it finish collecting data in a good amount of time?

Comment: see the below answer, Hope it will help you. <https://stackoverflow.com/a/52751547/10309265>?

Comment: Not relevant to my question